# Estimote beacons detector service in background

Tags: android, android-service, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I am trying to make a service on Android that would find Estimote beacons and push notifications to the user. I have downloaded sample code, and created new myService Activity using that code. Code is running, and I can see in LogCat that Android is scanning for beacons. Unfortunately no beacons are found. What is wrong with my code?

Or maybe I'm doing this in wrong way?

```
package com.osos.service;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import com.estimote.sdk.Beacon;
import com.estimote.sdk.BeaconManager;
import com.estimote.sdk.BeaconManager.MonitoringListener;
import com.estimote.sdk.BeaconManager.RangingListener;
import com.estimote.sdk.Region;
import com.estimote.sdk.utils.L;

import android.R;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service{
      private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 123;
    private BeaconManager beaconManager;
    Beacon beacon;
    private NotificationManager myNotificationManager;
     private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
private static final Region ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS_REGION = new Region("rid", null, null, null);
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1), 0);
//      beaconManager.setRangingListener(new RangingListener() {
//          
//          @Override
//          public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region arg0, List<Beacon> beacons_list) {
//              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//              
//          }
//      });
        Toast.makeText(this, "Jus paleidote OSOS serviza", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
          L.enableDebugLogging(true);
          Log.d(TAG, "onStartCOmmand");
            try{
                connectToService();
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("### problem ####");
                System.out.println(e);
            }


    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartCOmmand");

         beaconManager.setMonitoringListener(new MonitoringListener() {
              @Override
              public void onEnteredRegion(Region region, List<Beacon> beacons) {
                  switch(beacon.getMinor()){
                  case 11111: displayNotificationOne(1,"This is OSOS");
                  break;
                  default:        displayNotificationOne(1,"This is Sparta");

              }
              }
              @Override
              public void onExitedRegion(Region region) {
                  displayNotificationOne(2,"Exited OSOS");
              }
            });




        return  startId;



    }

    protected void displayNotificationOne(int i, String msg) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Display notif");
        // Invoking the default notification service
        Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this);

        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Simplify");
        mBuilder.setContentText("Jus turite nauju uzduociu");
        mBuilder.setTicker("Simplify: Jus turite nauju uzduociu");
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.arrow_up_float).setAutoCancel(true).build();

        long[] vibrate = {0,200,500 };
        mBuilder.setVibrate(vibrate);
        //mBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.groan));

        // Increase notification number every time a new notification arrives

        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
//      Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, Welcome.class);

        // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
        // the app to Home page
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent
//      stackBuilder.addParentStack(StartedReviewsActivity.class);


        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
//      stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT // can only be used once
                );
        // start the activity when the user clicks the notification text
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);


        myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // pass the Notification object to the system
        myNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }

     private void connectToService() {
           Log.e(TAG, "Connect to service");
//          getActionBar().setSubtitle("Scanning...");
//          adapter.replaceWith(Collections.<Beacon>emptyList());
            beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
              @Override
              public void onServiceReady() {
                try {
                  beaconManager.startRanging(ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS_REGION);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {

                  Log.e(TAG, "Cannot start ranging", e);
                }
              }
            });
          }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyService Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        beaconManager.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any luck ?? i am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is because you did not change the UUID, MAJOR and MINOR number of the beacon. Download the estimote sdk app on your phone and then you can get all three numbers replace them with the one you already have. It will start working.